# Difference between String and AttributedString

Tags: java, android

I am quite confused here. Today I came across this concept of [`AttributedString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html). But I am not able to find the exact difference for **String and AttributedString**. And more ever I am not able to convert this attributed String to String using the `toString()`. Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT 1**

Actually I want to provide Kerning attrribute for my text. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a holder for some consecutive list of characters, usually known as "text". `"Hello World"` is a `String`. It's a general-purpose data type that's used *a lot* all throughout Java.

An [`AttributedString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) holds text *and* some attributes. Attributes can be pretty much *anything*. Usually it's used for taggin some parts of the text with some language or even providing information about layout arguments (bold, italics, ...). It's a *very specific* data type that's used for *some specific areas* only.

Unless you have a *specific* reason to use `AttributedString`, you can pretty much forget that it exists.

Comment: No, I have little experience in Swing/AWT. But why didn't you actually ask how to provide kerning in Swing/AWT? That would have given you a more direct answer.

Comment: Actually I am working on android. I have to provide Kerning attrribute for my text. I couldn't find out an easy way to do this.

Comment: Still: why don't you simply ask **that** question? And not in the comment, but as a propper question!

Comment: I am doing a small research. So before I go for it, I thought that I should know what this is. And more ever I have searched a lot about kerning in android and I couldn't find one.